# Prove that a commutative ring is primitive if and only if it is a field.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, field-theory

I want to prove that a commutative ring $ R $ is primitive if and only if it is a field.

Here is my proof of "$\impliedby$":

Let $ R $ be a field. Then $ 0 $ and $ R $ is its only ideals. Since ann$_R(R) $ is an ideal of $ R $, ann$ _R(R)=R $ or ann$_R(R)=0 $. If ann$_R(R)=R  $, then $ rR=0 $ for all $ r\in R $. In particular, $ 1\cdot R=0 $, a contradiction. Hence ann$ _R(R)=0 $. Since $ R $ is a simple faithful module of $ R $, $ R $ is primitive.

Can anyone help me to get started with "$\implies$"?

Comment: I don't know how other people read it, but when I see "$A\iff B$" I think that $A\implies B$ is the sufficiency portion and $A\impliedby B$ is the necessity. That is, I take it we are talking about the sufficiency of $A$ to prove $B$ and the necessity of $A$ for $B$. Of course, you could interpret it with $A$ and $B$ interchanged as well.  Either way, it's not a very clear way of expressing yourself. Thankfully the rest of the context you gave dispelled any confusion.

Comment: Thanks, I really wasn't sure if I should say sufficiency or necessity. My focus was on whether $A$ is true, in the way that it is sufficient that $B$ is true in order for $A$ to be true. I'll introduce some implication arrows for clarity. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $R$ be primitive and commutative. Then for some maximal ideal $M$, $R/M$ is a faithful module.

But $M$ is the annihilator of $R/M$ so...

Comment: ... so $M=0$ since $R/M$ if faithful. Hence $R$ has no nonzero maximal ideals. We conclude that $R$ is a field. 

BUT, the fact that $R$ is primitive only implies that $R$ has SOME faithful simple module, not that $R/M$, for some maximal $M$, is faithful and simple. Of course $R/M$ is simple when $M$ is maximal, but why faithful?

Comment: @Barbara being primitive implies $R$ has some faithful simple module, yes, but every simple right module of $R$ is isomorphic to $R/M$ for some maximal right ideal.  It's easy: if $S$ is simple, just take $s\in S\setminus\{0\}$ and the map $R\to S$ given by $r\mapsto sr$, and the first isomorphism theorem says $S\cong R/M$ where $M$ is the kernel. $M$ has to be maximal by the correspondence theorem.